# What does ps aux | sort -rk 3,3 | head -n 5 meant?

Tags: shell

What does command `ps aux | sort -rk 3,3 | head -n 5` do ? Please explain each command .

Comment: +1 for the proper use of SE's homework solving automation mechanism.  Nah, just kidding about +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ps aux` = list all processes

`sort -rk 3,3` = sort by third field, in reverse order

`head -n 5` = show first 5 lines

So when piped together line this, simply shows the top 4 processes in terms of current CPU usage. (only 4, not 5, as one line will be a header title line)

Comment: By other two commands we are getting below result                                       $ ps aux | head -n 3
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  10368   304 ?        Ss    2014   0:55 init [3]
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<    2014   0:59 [migration/0]
 But what does sort -rk 3,3 command will do ? I mean how it shows the process name?

Comment: The `sort -rk 3 3` preserves the output format, it just changes the order.  So "-r" means reverse and "-k 3,3" means sort by third field.  As third field is %CPU, means it sorts by CPU usage in reverse order, thereby showing the heaviest CPU consumers first.

Comment: ok , i got it . I appreciate your prompt turn over.

Comment: Correct explanation of the commands but this whole command will not result in the top 4 processes in terms of CPU. There is no numeric sort so, for example, processes of 2% CPU will be displayed above processes running on 14% CPU.

Comment: Then what would be the exact command showing top 4 processes in terms of CPU?

Comment: I would use: `(LC_ALL=C head -n1; sort -nrk3) < <(ps aux)|head -5`